# Firebase Emulator interface says "The Emulator Suite UI only supports the (default) database right now" and Firestore does not show any data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I have two machines: my main desktop and my laptop (both are Linux).

On my desktop machine, Firebase and Firestore emulator works just fine. On Firestore interface, I can see the data that's been written to it.

On my laptop, however, Firestore emulator interface does not show anything and it tells "The Emulator Suite UI only supports the (default) database right now.".

[image: no data is shown in firestore emulator]

I develop with Flutter. In my app, the queries I do hits the emulator and I'm sure of it. The dev app persists the state and the data is not located in the real Firestore database.

I launch Firebase emulator as a VSCode task as below:

```
{
    "type": "shell",
    "label": "Firebase Emulator",
    "command": "firebase",
    "args": [
        "emulators:start",
        "--import",
        "firebase/dump",
        "--export-on-exit",
        "firebase/dump",
    ],
    "group": "test",
    "runOptions": {
        "runOn": "folderOpen"
    },
},
```

What might be the problem? Thanks in advance.

---

## Troubleshooting

I'm also trying some things to solve this. Here are some things I've done and haven't worked out.

- Removing Firestore dump and export folders.
- Explicitly adding `"database": "default"` to `firebase.json` (to `firestore` key).